# NServiceBus: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: nservicebus

```
NServiceBus version: 2.6.0.1505
```

NServiceBus doesn't like my WCF and OData service references.

They have been unit tested in different environment and are used in different systems successfully with same service uri's.

Has anyone experienced similar exceptions with NServiceBus?

From logs:

1) `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Resulting in: `An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'XXX.XXX'.`

```
Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'XXX.XXX'.
Element: XXX.XXX-->  XXX.XXX-->  DirectoryCatalog (Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XXX\XXX")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of NServiceBus is pretty old and I'm fairly sure that we dealt with a problem around serialization of URIs since then, so I guess my recommendation would be to upgrade to a newer release and see if that resolves it.